# Is this error normal. How to resolve GitHub error when it says

Tags: github

[I am trying to upload file on GitHub but this is the error it shows each time. How to solve this problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/byu9q.png)

Answer (score 0):

The instructions have been updated to clone over HTTPS. This should work with no issues:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/jakubroztocil/cloudtunes.git
```

This similar issue have been discussed in this [Github Thread](https://github.com/jakubroztocil/cloudtunes/issues/23)

Also, please look at this doc for more info : [Repo from GitHub](https://docs.github.com/en/github/creating-cloning-and-archiving-repositories/cloning-a-repository-from-github)